# после выполнения команды в консоли я больше ничего не могу туда ввести

Tags: node.js, сервер, консоль

Здравствуйте. Прописываю в консоли windows7 node server.js
Сервер запускается, после этого я могу открыть localhost:8080/index.html.
Но делаю это вручную, а мне хотелось бы запустить это через start в консоли.
А там уже ничего по какой-то причине не набирается. Как после запуска сервера сделать так, чтобы можно было дальше прописывать в консоли команды?

Comment: Открыть новую консоль. Или прописать все необходимые команды в одну команду.

Comment: Не все так просто. Открываю новую консоль, пишет - не существует связанной программы, а пишу в одну команду - запускает сервер, а остальную часть просто игнорирует

Comment: Насколько я помню, для открытия сразу в браузере есть ключ `-o`. Попробуйте его использовать. После старта сервера ничего писать нельзя.